# IOS: stop audio when I return in a view

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, wma

When I exit from a view I start a jingle and when i return in this view I want to stop this jingle (wma)

when I exit in IbAction I have this code:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                  @"file.wav"];

NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

but when I return in the view I try to write in viewWillAppear

```
AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(soundID);
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
```

but it don't work, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewWillAppear:` not will be called in some cases. You can use notification center (`[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`) or delegate to let your view now when to stop music.
There are some methods like `postNotification:` and `addObserver:`, check them.